# Regex exact text match is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to perform exact match of the text keyed in a textbox but, somehow it is working as partial match. I tried different options but could not figure out the cause.

```js
RegExp.escape = function (text) {
    //escape the +,[,?... characters
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}

var resultLbl = $('#ResultLbl');

$('#SearchTxtBox').bind('change keyup', function () {
  
resultLbl.text('');

var options = [];

options.push('[1]My]');
options.push('[2]My Name]');
options.push('[3]Name]');
options.push('[2]My Name]');

var searchStr = RegExp.escape($.trim($(this).val()));  

var searchArr = [];

if (searchStr != '' && searchStr != null) {
    searchStr = searchStr.replace(/\,/g, '\\ ')
    searchArr = searchStr.split('\\ ');
}

var search =  searchArr[0]; 

search = search.replace(/[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, '');

var regex = new RegExp($.trim(search), 'gi');

$.each(options, function (i, option) { 

if (option.match(regex) !== null) {
   resultLbl.append(option + ' ');
  }
});

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Search:
<input type="text" id="SearchTxtBox"/>
<br/>
<label id='ResultLbl'></label>
```

**Expectation:**

- If you key in the text 'Name' in textbox, only '[3]Name' should be
  matched.
- If you key in the text 'My Name' in textbox, only '[2]My
  Name' should be matched.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Use the regex /^[\d+]Name\]$/ instead of /Name/ to make sure that nothing else comes between the number and the search term, and that nothing comes after it

Comment: Sorry, the backslashes keep disappearing in my comment; the [ and ] and the ] at the end should be escaped.

Comment: @m69 Using the backtick character you can format `inline code` in your comments, and fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of complex pre-processing, you can just test if the string matches this pattern:

```
^\[\d+\]<searchStr>\]$
```

with

```
var regex = new RegExp("^\\[\\d+\\]" + $.trim(searchStr) + "\\]$", 'gi');
```

Here is an updated snippet:

```js
    RegExp.escape = function (text) {
        //escape the +,[,?... characters
        return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
    }

    var resultLbl = $('#ResultLbl');

    $('#SearchTxtBox').bind('change keyup', function () {
      
    resultLbl.text('');

    var options = [];

    options.push('[1]My]');
    options.push('[2]My Name]');
    options.push('[3]Name]');
    options.push('[2]My Name]');

    var searchStr = RegExp.escape($.trim($(this).val()));  

    var regex = new RegExp("^\\[\\d+\\]" + $.trim(searchStr) + "\\]$", 'gi');

    $.each(options, function (i, option) { 

    if (option.match(regex) !== null) {
       resultLbl.append(option + ' ');
      }
    });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Search:
<input type="text" id="SearchTxtBox"/>
<br/>
<label id='ResultLbl'></label>
```